# IDing an HTML Table Class Column Heading

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, datatables

I have a HTML table I have created by the HTML Table class in Codeigniter. The last columns in most but not all of the columns is an Actions column that houses two icons. One for the edit icon and one for the delete icon. This table also has datatables being rendered on it. So by default all columns are sortable and I am wanting to disable that column on all tables if the table includes that column as not sortable.

My question is what would be the best way to apply this. Should I try and figure out how to apply a an id to that column and then in the js try and figure out how to call that column and disable the feature or what is the best option or what are all my other options?

Comment: I don't understand this: " I am wanting to disable that column on all tables if the table includes that column as not sortable."  Are you saying the edit/delete column is sometimes sortable?

Comment: Not all my tables have the actions column. But the ones that do have the column as sortable sense its setup by default.

Comment: how do you generate the table ? can you post code for that